# How do I enable subtitles for Voxophone audio logs?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

In both previous BioShock games the audio logs came with subtitles, but in this game I'm not getting any despite having both art and dialogue subtitles enabled. Is it supposed to be like that, or am I just missing something?

I'm playing the 360 version if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, unfortunately, the way it's supposed to be. You can't enable subtitles for voxophone records, but you can access the transcripts through the gameplay menu (Default PC key: O).